# JavaScript -how to get array value with some condition?

Tags: javascript

I want to filter the **let data** array. I created map function with some condition for filter the let data array value to get the **result ["true","false","true"]** but I also want to display the let data array value when the result is true.

Here is my code:

```
 let data = 
{
    "days": {
        "Monday": {
            "checkin": "23:00",
            "checkout": "10:00"
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "checkin": "07:00",
            "checkout": "14:00"
        },
        "Wednesdy": {
            "checkin": "07:00",
            "checkout": "04:00"
        },
    }
}
let day = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesdy'];
const ds = Object.keys(data.days);

const getin = (day) =day.map (d=> ds.indexOf(d)>=0 && data.days[d].checkin >= data.days[d].checkout); 


console.log("===Results===",getin);
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/benjamin0523/8abtysuz/17/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you want to `filter` then return all items `matching condition`.

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) along with `.reduce` to achieve it.

```js
let data = 
{
    "days": {
        "Monday": {
            "checkin": "23:00",
            "checkout": "10:00"
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "checkin": "07:00",
            "checkout": "14:00"
        },
        "Wednesdy": {
            "checkin": "07:00",
            "checkout": "04:00"
        },
    }
}
let day = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesdy'];
var result = Object.entries(data.days).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if(day.indexOf(key) >= 0 && value.checkin >= value.checkout)
    acc.push({[key]: value});
    
  return acc;
}, []); 
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're stuck at this stage since it is quite trivial.

In this line:

```
const getin = (day) =day.map (d=> ds.indexOf(d)>=0 && data.days[d].checkin >= data.days[d].checkout);
```

you are essentially allotting the result of `ds.indexOf(d)>=0 && data.days[d].checkin >= data.days[d].checkout` to `getin` and `day`.

`ds.indexOf(d)>=0 && data.days[d].checkin >= data.days[d].checkout` is a boolean since it is the output of two checks.

You could use something like this to *use the check* instead of returning the check itself: `ds.indexOf(d)>=0 && data.days[d].checkin >= data.days[d].checkout ? d : false`. `?` is a condition operator which helps reduce typing if else statements.

The modified code:

```
 let data = 
{
    "days": {
        "Monday": {
            "checkin": "23:00",
            "checkout": "10:00"
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "checkin": "07:00",
            "checkout": "14:00"
        },
        "Wednesdy": {
            "checkin": "07:00",
            "checkout": "04:00"
        },
    }
}
let day = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesdy'];
const ds = Object.keys(data.days);

const getin = (day) =day.map (d=> ds.indexOf(d)>=0 && data.days[d].checkin >= data.days[d].checkout ? d : false); 


console.log("===Results===",getin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following by pushing the object in a new array when the filter condition is true,

```js
 let data = 
{
    "days": {
        "Monday": {
            "checkin": "23:00",
            "checkout": "10:00"
        },
        "Tuesday": {
            "checkin": "07:00",
            "checkout": "14:00"
        },
        "Wednesdy": {
            "checkin": "07:00",
            "checkout": "04:00"
        },
    }
}
let day = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesdy'];
const ds = Object.keys(data.days);
const daysRes = [];
const getin = (day) =day.map (d=> {
  if(ds.indexOf(d)>=0 && data.days[d].checkin >= data.days[d].checkout) {
    daysRes.push(data.days[d]);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}); 


console.log("===Results===",getin);
console.log("===ResultsDays===",daysRes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let data = {
  days: {
    Monday: {
      checkin: "23:00",
      checkout: "10:00"
    },
    Tuesday: {
      checkin: "07:00",
      checkout: "14:00"
    },
    Wednesdy: {
      checkin: "07:00",
      checkout: "04:00"
    }
  }
};
let day = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesdy"];
const ds = Object.keys(data.days);

const getin = Object.values(data.days).filter(d => (d.checkin >= d.checkout));

console.log("===Results===", getin);
```

**Why your code returns `["true","false","true"]`?**

You are making use of array.map you are returning the result of the operation
`ds.indexOf(d)>=0 && data.days[d].checkin >= data.days[d].checkout`
This response is always boolean, either true or false.

`array.map` always returns a value corresponding to each node in the array. In your case it returned a boolean value after the comparison.

Go for `array.filter`, this will create a new array from an existing one by returning the entire node of the array dependig on a condition, which is your actual requirement.